# I keep geting this error isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead) on line 2

Tags: php, html

//line 2 is at the begining of the if statement

```
 <?php
        if (isset($_POST = 'submitted')){
//code here
  }
    ?>
```

Comment: you should use if(isset($_POST)){ // your code }

Comment: `$_POST = 'submitted'` means set value `submitted` to variable `$_POST`. Why do you do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

Obvioulsy what you need is

```
if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {
    // code here
}
```

`isset($_POST['submitted'])` checks if key `'submitted'` isset in your `$_POST` array.

In your code

```
if (isset($_POST = 'submitted')) {
```

`isset` checks the result of assigning value `'submitted'` to `$_POST`. But the result of assignment is some value, and this value can not be checked if it is set. As a side effect your `$_POST` is overwritten and you lose all your data inside it.

Comment: If answer helps you - you can accept it. More here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work